# Can we use design and make in this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I know that we usually say:
We make/produce films.
But my teacher said we can also say:
We design films.
Is it correct to say designing films?

Comment: Why would it be wrong?

Comment: It is a very unexpected usage of 'design' but one that does make some sense with respect to _any_ artistic creation. It asks to be explained though, which is to say that if you say  'This film was designed by so-and-so'. People would go crosseyed and ask you to elaborate. A lot. But then it would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I have read that the British-Dutch director Peter Greenaway 'architects' his films. And it makes sense, if you see one of his films. 
It may indeed be fitting to say that some films are designed. Perhaps correct to say that others are put together with misprinted directions.

Answer (score -1):

Alas, the term "**design**" in the context of film production is already taken:

> In film and television, a **production designer (PD)** is the person responsible for the overall visual look of the production. Production designers have a key creative role in the creation of motion pictures and television. Working directly with the director, cinematographer, and producer, they must select the settings and style to visually tell the story. The term *production designer* was coined by William Cameron Menzies while he was working on the film *Gone with the Wind*. Previously (and often subsequently) the people with the same responsibilities were called *art directors*. It is sometimes also described as *scenic design* or *set design*.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_designer)

Therefore, when you say *"I designed this film"* it will be understood that you were the **art director** for the production. Not the **director** or the **producer**, who "*made*" or "*produced*" the film.